# Update mime type from ~/.mime.types?

Tags: mime-type

The file /etc/mime.types tells that you can have a file named ~/.mime.types in your user directory and Ubuntu will grab all your defined types from there. However, I couldn't do that. I've read that there was another way to do it, but I would like to know if this way is still possible.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 3):

### Create a new mime type only for your user

**Replace `foo` with your file extension, in my example I have used `foo` *FOUR* times**

- Create a new XML file

  ```
  nano ~/.local/share/mime/packages/foo.xml
  ```
- Add the XML code below

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="text/foo">
      <comment>Todos Text file</comment>
      <glob pattern="*.foo"/>
      <glob pattern="*.FOO"/>
    </mime-type>
  </mime-info>
  ```
- Update the database

  ```
  update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
  ```

Comment: That's right, but I guess he says the fact that it should be possible to add a type as /etc/mime.types mentions: `Users can add their own types if they wish by creating a ".mime.types" file in their home directory.  Definitions included there will take precedence over those listed here.`

Comment: This does not help ... this way I can just define type which cannot be associated with any application in `nautilus` ... I mean there is not even `Open With` tab when I right-click and select `Properties` in Nautilus